# How to replace a .phml file without rewrite the entire block

Tags: magento-1.9, page-layouts

I have a custom extension working fine. It has some features that only usable when this extension is installed and enabled so I decided to create a custom `footer.phtml` and put it under my extension template folder `app/design/frontend/company/custom/template/module/footer.phtml`. Current `footer.phtml` is loaded in `layout/page.xml` like below:

```
<!-- header part -->
<default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">

            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

                <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start" translate="label">
                <label>Page Top</label>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_notices" name="global_notices" as="global_notices" template="page/html/notices.phtml" />

            <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Header</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
                <label>Left Column</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
            <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
                <label>Right Column</label>
            </block>
            
            <block type="core/text_list" name="banner_a" as="banner_a" translate="label">
                <label>Banner A</label>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Footer</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
                <label>Page Bottom</label>
                <block type="page/html_cookieNotice" name="global_cookie_notice" as ="global_cookie_notice" template="page/html/cookienotice.phtml" before="-" />
            </block>
        </block>

        <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
    </default>
<!-- other part -->
```

In my own `company_module.xml` I tried to load my own `footer.phtml` like below:

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="custom/module/footer.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                                <label>Page Footer</label>
                                <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
                        </block>
                        <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
                        <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
                </block>
         </block>
</default>
```

Clearly it doesn't work in that way because of the other parts are not loaded. I'm stuck here and believe Magento has its own way to override a single template.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself. I should reference the template instead of override the whole thing straight away.

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <!-- because footer's parent is root -->
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="my_extension_template_folder/footer.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

I also realised the way to add things in the footer (not replace the whole footer)

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
            <block type="core/template" name="content_name" template="my_extension_template_folder/content_to_add.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```